# Laravel $id return 'en' instead of id

Tags: php, laravel

My route:

```
Route::group([
'prefix' => '{locale}',
'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'],
'middleware' => 'setlocale'],  
function () {

// GROUP FOR AUTHENTICATION
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth:sanctum', 'verified',
], function () {

    // GROUP FOR ADMIN
    Route::group([
        'prefix' => 'admin',
        'as' => 'admin.',
    ], function () {
        Route::resource('partner', PartnerFormController::class);
    });
});
```

});

My view that when I click, it shows the details page:

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.partner.show', $partner->id) }}" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit</a>
```

My controller:

```
public function show(PartnerForm $partnerForm, $id)
{

    $details = DB::table('partner_forms')->where('id', $id)
    ->first();

    return view('admin.partner-details', compact('details'));
}
```

I  tried to call $details->name or $details->in my view details page but it didnt work. The URL is working properly by displaying http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/admin/partner/1 but when i dd() my $id in controller it returns en, which I believe is the en from the URL.

Comment: By clicking Edit under your post, you can edit your post.

Comment: @khairin-chan Do you have defined your route resource in any route group ?

Comment: @UrjaSatodiya yes, 1st group is locale, 2nd group is for authentication, and the last group is under admin.

Comment: Ok, @khairin-chan can you update it here in your post, please ?

Comment: @UrjaSatodiya yes i already update it

Comment: Ok, I think you do not need that extra `$id` parameter, first one `$partnerForm` is enough, Please check it will return you the selected PartnerForm model object.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of sending the ID along with the route, send all the variables and enter the information into the new page in the control without the need to connect to the database and using route model binding.

Example :

- view A

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.partner.show', $partner) }}">Foo</a>
```

- route

```
Route::get('.../{partner}', [Controller::class, 'Bar'])->name('admin.partner.show');
```

- controller

```
public function Bar(Partner_MODEL $partner){
    return view('view_name', compact('partner'));
}
```

- view B : use $partner.
- Important note : in (route, controller method, compact meethod) The variable name must be similar

Comment: do i still need to use the route u suggested since i alrdy hv the route::resource?

Comment: it's a document if you have any part of that, so used

Comment: $partner is your details

Comment: it still detects $id as 'en' when i dd() it though. i dont understand why didnt it get 1

Comment: Why would you suggest a GET route if there is a resource route used?